# How to store variable in property in jmeter using beanshell post processor and refrence that variable in next request.

Tags: properties, jmeter, beanshell

I am hitting an http url and need  url contents into property in jmeter.
I have done the fetching part from url,but unable to store the value in properties using the jmeter.

For e.g.
Request is like
http://url/user=admin,password=admin

I need property in jmeters

property1(user)=admin
property(password)=admin

Comment: Your question is little confusing. Can you simply state your problem and what you want to do. I don't think bean-shell processor or Jmeter property is required at all. I can propose simpler solutions if you can further explain your problem statement/requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Given you have already extracted what you need it might be easier  to use  [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function like:

```
${__setProperty(foo,bar,)}
```

creates "foo" property with the value of "bar"

---

If you still want to go the "Beanshell" way, you can use `props` shorthand which provides read-write access to JMeter Properties (in fact it's instance of [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)) for properties manipulation.

The Beanshell script:

```
props.put("foo", "bar");
```

will create a property "foo" having value of "bar".

Returning to your use case, if your URL looks like `http://example.com/?user=admin&password=admin` use the following Beanshell code:

```
Map parameters = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgumentsAsMap();

String user = parameters.get("user");
String password = parameters.get("password");

props.put("user", user);
props.put("password", password);
```

should do what you need. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.

Comment: properties are global for the whole JVM

Comment: Then in next thread group how to reference the property declared in Thread Group 1.Will I directly reference the property variable in the http request?